# Mail is marked as spam although SPF and DKIM pass

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim, spam

- I have configured Postfix to send mail from a dedicated server hosted let's on IP X.X.X.X and domain name example.com.
- DKIM, SPF always pass when I send mail locally from that host but still ends up in Spam folder (Gmail, Hotmail).
- I've also properly configured the Reverse DNS of said server.
- Here is the SPF record I'm using in case you need it : v=spf1 ip4:X.X.X.X -all and the mail header received from [Hotmail](http://pastie.org/pastes/6573842/text) and [Gmail](http://pastie.org/pastes/6573867/text)
- I made sure the IP was not blacklisted anywhere using mxtoolbox.com

What else do I need to check ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: SPF and DKIM aren't anti-spam measures but anti-forgery measures.

Comment: ISPs are known to block domains, or give lower reputation to newly registered domain names - up until around 2 weeks old apparently.

How old is your domain?

Answer (score 1):

Having a properly working DKIM and SPF are not necessarily guarantees that some site administrator will not blacklist you.  There are many other lists and processes especially some of the large sites put in play to prevent unwanted user email.

I'd suggest that you contact Gmail and Hotmail and find out why you are being blacklisted and then correct the problem.  That is the only way that a blacklist will be lifted .... i.e. by action of the site administrator.